# CakePHP 1.3 - app_controller.php $helpers were not inherited

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

CakePHP: 1.3
OS: Ubuntu 10.10
Apache: 2.2
PHP: 5.3+
MySQL: 5.1

I have the **/app/app_controller.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Ajax', 'Javascript');
}
```

When I try use any helpers above, I get error... because it was **'not loaded'** (you understand?!)

But, when I put the same code in any Controller, for example:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array('Html','Ajax', 'Javascript', 'Form');
```

*Works great :)*

**BUT! What I did wrong in app_controller.php?**
app_controller not load $helpers? the documentation says it load "everything".

Sorry my English ... I am Brazilian and I need to use "Google Translate " in some cases =P

Comment: Did this get solved? I just started seeing the same thing and it's not something I've ever run across before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PHP5, try using "public" instead of var when declaring the helpers array.  I think that will correct the inheritance issue.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Ajax', 'Javascript');
}
```

Comment: sorry my friend but did not work. when I put the $helpers in /app/app_controller.php, either as "var" or as "public" doesn't work.

Only if I add them to your controller, such as "UsersController".